# Build My Own Advertising Network

Tags: google-adsense, advertising, publishing

I have a few ideas that I think would be pretty game changing for online advertising and I would like to build my own network but I don't know where to start.  I know it will take a lot of time for major publishers to get on board but I am more curious about the technical side.

What language/database model and framework are modern ad networks built on?  Basically I want to build an advertising network that registers views per page and allows publishers to manage the look of their own ads and let's the users interact with the ads.  Is there any good information on doing something like this or any framework you can suggest to build on?

I know this would get complicated pretty fast so if you have suggestions for ad networks that let you customize them heavily I would be glad to hear your suggestions.

Comment: I'm happy that you want to take on Google Adsense too.

Comment: Although I can't really help you out here, I am just asking myself what kind of game changing magic you came up with. Everything you described is already implemented in Google Adsense plus some major publisher tools to adapt Adsense to their needs through the API: https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.2/reference/index

Comment: haha well I wasn't listing the new things I want to add. those are more on the user side and how the website visitor interacts with the ads

Answer (score 2):

There is no single language or database model that modern ad networks are built on; there are so many of them and they vary greatly.

But you could build your own ad network using an existing ad server, then create your own system if things take off for you. Here are serveral popular ad servers:

- [OpenX](http://www.openx.com/) has a paid hosted product, [OpenX Enterprise](http://www.openx.com/publisher/enterprise-ad-server), a free hosted product, [OpenX OnRamp](http://www.openx.com/publisher/compare-ad-server-products), and an open-source self-hosted product called [OpenX Source](http://www.openx.com/publisher/compare-ad-server-products).
- [Epom](http://epom.com/) is a paid, hosted platform with tools aimed directly at people running [ad networks](http://epom.com/networks).
- [Adzerk](http://www.adzerk.com/) is a paid, hosted platform with options for [networks](http://www.adzerk.com/for-networks/).
- [BittAds](http://www.bittads.com/) is a paid, hosted platform with a [free account](http://www.bittads.com/pricing/) to serve up to 10 million ad impressions per month.
- [TrafficSpaces](https://www.trafficspaces.com/) is a hosted platform to sell your own ads. It's aimed at publishers, but their [large plan](https://www.trafficspaces.com/plans/) lets you build your own ad network.

It would also be worth researching your competitors; check out other popular independent ad networks such as [BuySellAds](http://buysellads.com/) to see how they handle advertisers and publishers.